# How to send email with celery without using django in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have a email.py this is okay, it works without celery.
I want to make it work with celery for queue.

I can't find single tutorial for working with celery in python without django.

I have checked https://readthedocs.org/projects/celery/  but  it is so confusing

Comment: This [blog post](https://medium.com/@juwelariful1/send-mail-in-django-with-gmail-and-smtp-include-celery-and-gmail-configuration-4b07ae4f8542) has a step by step basis to setup django app with sent email feature. You should clarify more on what issues you're getting and what have you tried

Comment: As i mentioned, I dont want to use DJANGO, I want celery without DJANGO

Comment: I don't think that's what celery is used for. Celery is just a task queue that allow handle incoming requests asynchronously. You can sent email without Django using [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) library. You can follow a simple setup in [this blog](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/)

Comment: yeah i know, i want to put emails in a queue with celery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def send_email():
    #write your code here
```

it is that simple.